# Visual Studio Code - Emmet / Intellisense autocomplete does not seem to work inside attributes

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense, emmet

I'm just starting out learning html/css in vscode and came across this issue.

1. New HTML doc
2. Type inp and then press TAB
3. As expected you get the full, pre-filled and text pre-selected
   `<input type="text" name="" id="">`
4. If one now types, "text" gets replaced with the new characters, as expected
5. Pressing Tab automatically goes in between the " " of `name=`, as expected
6. If you then start typing, you do not get any auto-complete suggestions. So, if you have had a `<label for="test1">`, and then an `<input...`, you would not get the `test1` suggestion when typing in the "pre-selected" syntax.
7. If you, however, after pressing tab press the left arrow and then right arrow to move the caret back and forth a character(and therefore losing the pre-selection) you now get the auto-suggestion when typing.

Am I missing something?

Example here: https://streamable.com/hgwtyp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else on github pointed me in the right direction. This is what I was after:

`"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false`

Comment: This answer is invaluable!!! Hours looking for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to press ctrl+space there to get suggestions immediately. Also, you can modify the config like:

```js
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": true
    },
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on",
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": true,
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem work. Also, CTRL+Shift does not do anything either. I've updated my original post with a video of what I'm after

Comment: It should be CTRL+Space.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. Any reason why CTRL+Space is needed inside " "? Or is it just "By design"?

Comment: The `quickSuggestions` `strings` setting should fix it but seems a little wonky.  Try a reload of vscode after making the settings change.

Comment: extremely sorry. I mistyped ctrl+space as ctrl+shift.